# how to upload multiple files with single browse button?

Tags: php, file-upload

I make a php page in which i get the files array and count array element, i want to apply loop and loop work until count like if count=3,then code run 3 times and 3 files uploaded.

Here is my code:

```
apply_now.tpl

{literal}
<script>
    function applySubmit() {
        $("#ApplicationForm").hide();
        $("#ProgressBar").show();
        $("#applyForm").ajaxSubmit({
            url: $("#applyForm").attr("action"),
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#messageBox").html(data);
            }
    });
    return false;
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#applyForm").jqTransform();
});
</script>
{/literal}

<div id="ProgressBar" style="display:none"><img src="{$GLOBALS.site_url}/system/ext/jquery/progbar.gif" alt="[[Please wait ...]]" />[[Please wait ...]]</div>

<div id="ApplicationForm">
{if $is_data_submitted && !$errors}
    <p class="message">[[You applied successfully]]</p>
{else}
    {foreach from=$errors key=error_code item=error_message}
            <p class="error">
                {if $error_code  eq 'EMPTY_VALUE'} [[Enter Security code]]
                {elseif $error_code eq 'NOT_VALID'} [[Security code is not valid]]
                {elseif $error_code eq 'SEND_ERROR'} [[There was an error while sending your application.]]
                {else}[[{$error_message}]]
                {/if}
            </p>
    {/foreach}
    {include file='field_errors.tpl'}
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{$GLOBALS.site_url}/apply-now/" id="applyForm">
        <input type="hidden" name="is_data_submitted" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="listing_id" value="{$listing_id}">
        {if NOT $GLOBALS.current_user.logged_in}
            <fieldset>
                <div class="inputName">[[Your name]]:</div>
                <div class="inputField"><input type="text" name="name" value="{$request.name}" /></div>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <div class="inputName">[[Your e-mail]]:</div>
                <div class="inputField"><input type="text" name="email" value="{$request.email}" /></div>
            </fieldset>
        {/if}
        <fieldset>
            <div class="inputName">[[Cover letter (optional)]]:</div>
            <div class="inputField"><textarea name="comments" rows="5">{$request.comments}</textarea></div>
        </fieldset>
        {if $GLOBALS.current_user.logged_in && $resume}
            <fieldset>
                <div class="inputName">[[Select your resume]]:</div>
                <div class="inputField">
                    <select name="id_resume[]" multiple="multiple">
                        <option value="0" selected="selected">[[Select your resume]]</option>
                        {html_options options=$resume selected=$request.id_resume}
                    </select>
                    <br />or
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        {/if}
        <fieldset>
            <div class="inputName">[[Attach your resume]]:</div>
            <div class="inputField"><input type="file" name="file_tmp[]" multiple /></div>
        </fieldset>
        {if $isCaptcha == 1}
            <fieldset>
                <div class="inputName">[[$captcha.caption]]:</div>
                <div class="inputField">{input property=$captcha.id object=$captchaObject}</div>
            </fieldset>
        {/if}
        <input type="hidden" name="anonymous" value="1" />
        {if $form_fields}
            <fieldset>
                {include file="questionnaire.tpl" form_fields=$form_fields}
            </fieldset>
        {/if}
        <fieldset>
            <div class="inputName">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="inputButton"><input id="SubmitButton" type="submit" value="[[Send]]" onclick="return applySubmit();"/></div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
{/if}
</div>
```

and here is my apply_now.php file code:

```
 <?php

 class SJB_Classifieds_ApplyNow extends SJB_Function
 {
public function isAccessible()
{
    $this->setPermissionLabel('apply_for_a_job');
    return parent::isAccessible();
}

public function execute()
{
    $errors = array();
    $field_errors = array();
    $tp = SJB_System::getTemplateProcessor();
    $loggedIn = SJB_UserManager::isUserLoggedIn();
    $current_user_sid = SJB_UserManager::getCurrentUserSID();

    $controller      = new SJB_SendListingInfoController($_REQUEST);
    $isDataSubmitted = false;
    $isCaptcha       = 0;
    if (SJB_PluginManager::isPluginActive('CaptchaPlugin') && SJB_System::getSettingByName('contactUserCaptcha') == 1) {
        $isCaptcha = 1;
    }
    $captcha      = new SJB_Captcha($_REQUEST, 'modal');
    $captcha_form = SJB_ObjectMother::createForm($captcha);
    $captcha_form->registerTags($tp);
    $tp->assign('captcha', array_pop($captcha_form->form_fields));
    $tp->assign('captchaObject', $captcha);

    $jobInfo = SJB_ListingManager::getListingInfoBySID($controller->getListingID());
    if ($controller->isListingSpecified()) {
        if ($controller->isDataSubmitted()) {
            $captcha_errors = array();
            if ($isCaptcha && !$captcha_form->isDataValid($captcha_errors)) {
                foreach ($captcha_errors as $error)
                    $errors[$error] = true;
            }
            else {
                // получим уникальный id для файла в uploaded_files

                $file_id_current = 'application_' . md5(microtime());
                $upload_manager = new SJB_UploadFileManager();
                $upload_manager->setFileGroup('files');
                $upload_manager->setUploadedFileID($file_id_current);
                for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file_tmp']['name']); $i++){

$file_name = $upload_manager->uploadFile($_FILES['file_tmp']['name'][$i]);
}
                $id_file = mysql_insert_id();

                $post = $controller->getData();
                $listingId = 0;


                $mimeType = isset($_FILES['file_tmp']['type']) ? $_FILES['file_tmp']['type'] : '';

                if (isset($_FILES['file_tmp']['size']) && $file_name != '' && $_FILES['file_tmp']['size'] == 0) {
                    $errors['FILE_IS_EMPTY'] = 'The uploaded file should not be blank';
                }

                if (!empty($_FILES['file_tmp']['name'])){
                    $fileFormats = explode(',',SJB_System::getSettingByName('file_valid_types'));
                    foreach ( $_FILES['file_tmp']['name'] as $key => $file ) {
                        $fileInfo = pathinfo($_FILES['file_tmp']['name'][$key]);
                        if ( !in_array(strtolower($fileInfo['extension']), $fileFormats) ) {
                            $errors['NOT_SUPPORTED_FILE_FORMAT'] = strtolower($fileInfo['extension']) . ' ' . SJB_I18N::getInstance()->gettext(null, 'is not in an acceptable file format');
                        }
                    }
                }

                if ($file_name == '' && $listingId == 0) {
                    $canAppplyWithoutResume = false;
                    SJB_Event::dispatch('CanApplyWithoutResume', $canAppplyWithoutResume);
                    if (!$canAppplyWithoutResume) {
                        $errors['APPLY_INPUT_ERROR'] = 'Please select file or resume';
                    }
                }
                else if (SJB_Applications::isApplied($post['submitted_data']['listing_id'], $current_user_sid) && !is_null($current_user_sid)) {
                    $errors['APPLY_APPLIED_ERROR'] = 'You already applied';
                }

                $res = false;
                $listing_info = '';
                $notRegisterUserData = $_POST;
                $score = 0;
                // для зарегестрированного пользователя получим поля email и name
                // для незарегестрированных - поля name и email приходят с формы

                    if(!empty($file_name))
                        $file_name = 'files/files/'. $file_name;
                    if (!SJB_Notifications::sendApplyNow($post, $file_name, $listing_info, $current_user_sid, $notRegisterUserData, $score))
                        $errors['SEND_ERROR'] = true;



    $tp->assign('request', $_REQUEST);
    $tp->assign('isCaptcha', $isCaptcha);
    $tp->assign('errors', $errors);
    $tp->assign('listing_id', $controller->getListingID());
    $tp->assign('is_data_submitted', $isDataSubmitted);
    $tp->display('apply_now.tpl');
}
 }
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Anyone who apply loop in my code and loop end at count

Comment: Can you try to explain better what you want? because I can't understand most of what you say, like "apply loop" or the error "you already applied"

Comment: i want to select more than one files in select box and then these value count in apply_now.php i want to apply same job with different resumes that i selected from select box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

example.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
<body>
    <form action="my_parser.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <p><input type="file" name="file_array[]"></p>
        <p><input type="file" name="file_array[]"></p>
        <p><input type="file" name="file_array[]"></p>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload all files">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

my_parser.php

```
<?php
    if(isset($_FILES['file_array'])){
        $name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['name'];
        $tmp_name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['tmp_name'];
        $type_array = $_FILES['file_array']['type'];
        $size_array = $_FILES['file_array']['size'];
        $error_array = $_FILES['file_array']['error'];
        for($i = 0; $i < count($tmp_name_array); $i++){
            if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_array[$i], "test_uploads/".$name_array[$i])){
                echo $name_array[$i]." upload is complete<br>";
            } else {
                echo "move_uploaded_file function failed for ".$name_array[$i]."<br>";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add the `multiple` attribute to your `<input>` tag in html, your files will be available in PHP as an array, under `$_FILES["file_tmp"]`.

### HTML

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" name="file_tmp[]" multiple>
```

### PHP

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES["file_tmp"]["name"]); $i++){
    //your upload code

    //You can access your file as following:
    $filename = $_FILES["file_tmp"]['tmp_name'][$i];
}
```

In the future, please do not post your entire code, but only the relevant snippet(s). Noone wants to read through all of that code just to find your issue.

Comment: How did it not work? Did it give any error? Please try yourself what causes it to not work. Also, why did you re-add the entire block of code? You will not get a lot of people to help you because noone wants to read through 1000 lines of code to find the 1 important line of code. Furthermore, don't add tags that are irrelevant to the question.

Comment: i updated my code plz see my code i include your code in my code but no file uploading

Comment: @Arif Can you remove all of the irrelevant code? I don't want to waste 15 minutes trying to find what you changed.

Comment: @Arif And do you get any error? How exactly is it "not working"?

Comment: If the answer was nice enough to accept, maybe it is nice enough for you to also upvote it @MuhammadArif

Answer (score 1):

A slight changes in above mentioned code..

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES["file_tmp"]["name"]); $i++){     
   $filename[] = $_FILES["file_tmp"]['tmp_name'][$i];
}
```