# how to remove pathinfo error from php page?

Tags: php, file-upload

i make a template in which i select multiple files and i make php page in which i upload the files but when i upload the files it gives me error like

```
Warning: pathinfo() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\jobboard\system\user-scripts\classifieds\apply_now.php on line 67
```

here is my code:

```
<input type="file" name="file_tmp[]" multiple />
```

and here is my apply_now.php:

```
if (!empty($_FILES['file_tmp']['name'])){
    $fileFormats = explode(',',SJB_System::getSettingByName('file_valid_types'));
    foreach ( $_FILES['file_tmp']['name'] as $file ) {
        $fileInfo = pathinfo($file);
        if ( !in_array(strtolower($fileInfo['extension']), $fileFormats) ) {
            $errors['NOT_SUPPORTED_FILE_FORMAT'] = strtolower($fileInfo['extension']) . ' ' . SJB_I18N::getInstance()->gettext(null, 'is not in an acceptable file format');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by the fact that you are giving an array as argument, instead of a string, just as the error message tells you.

This can be fixed by changing your foreach code to the following:

```
foreach ( $_FILES['file_tmp']['name'] as $key => $file ) {
    $fileInfo = pathinfo($_FILES['file_tmp']['name'][$key]);
    if ( !in_array(strtolower($fileInfo['extension']), $fileFormats) ) {
        $errors['NOT_SUPPORTED_FILE_FORMAT'] = strtolower($fileInfo['extension']) . ' ' . SJB_I18N::getInstance()->gettext(null, 'is not in an acceptable file format');
    }
}
```

Please also refer to my code in my answer on your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22355746/2539335

Answer (score 0):

If you upload many files then $_FILES['file_tmp']['name'] will be an array.
You should make foreach loop

```
foreach ($_FILES["pictures"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["pictures"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = $_FILES["pictures"]["name"][$key];
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "data/$name");
    }
}
```

In you code replace:

```
$fileInfo = pathinfo($_FILES['file_tmp']['name']);
if ( !in_array(strtolower($fileInfo['extension']), $fileFormats) ) {
    $errors['NOT_SUPPORTED_FILE_FORMAT'] = strtolower($fileInfo['extension']) . ' ' . SJB_I18N::getInstance()->gettext(null, 'is not in an acceptable file format');
}
```

With:

```
foreach ( $_FILES['file_tmp']['name'] as $file ) {
    $fileInfo = pathinfo($file);
    if ( !in_array(strtolower($fileInfo['extension']), $fileFormats) ) {
        $errors['NOT_SUPPORTED_FILE_FORMAT'] = strtolower($fileInfo['extension']) . ' ' . SJB_I18N::getInstance()->gettext(null, 'is not in an acceptable file format');
    }
}
```

Comment: i used your code but my files not uploaded and not move in database

Comment: $upload_manager->uploadFile - must take filename? and did you give all code from 'apply_now.php'?

Comment: Oh, dear Lord! 15 level inner blocks! It should be decomposed by class and functions... I need some time to understant this code.

Comment: In you code there is some comments in Russian, it is interesting! Are you russian?